# Jquery/JS function not applies

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

building html that use jquery to get data from web API.
In the beginning of my script I did a function that checks the value of dropdown (what is selected) and according to the selected it's fill the global variable.

```
var $seldom;
$(document).ready(function () {
    function chkdom() {
        if ($("#dropdomain").val('Europa')) {
            $seldom = '192.168.5.37';
        }
        else if ($("#dropdomain").val("Canada")) {
            $seldom = '172.168.0.1';
        }
    }
```

after defining the function I calling it immediately to check it and fill the variable.

finally by Clicking on search it should check what selected from dropdown and according to that fill again the variable and start GET function with the modified URL

```
$('#search').click(function () {
            chkdom();
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://" + $seldom + "/api/find/" + $("input#user").val(),
```

**Problem**: After I start the debug the `$selcom` always get the value of  `'192.168.5.37'` doesn't matter what I do.
Tried to debug it many ways but couldn't find why it's assigning that value.
Please assist as it should be so simple but I must missed something.

Here is the part of the code from the begining:

```
var $seldom;
$(document).ready(function () {
    function chkdom() {
        if ($("#dropdomain").val('Europa')) {
            $seldom = '192.168.5.37';
        }
        else if ($("#dropdomain").val("Canada")) {
            $seldom = '172.16.0.1';
        }
    }
    chkdom();
    alert($seldom);
    alert($("#dropdomain").val());

    $('#search').click(function () {
            chkdom();
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://" + $seldom + "/api/find/" + $("input#user").val(),
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'Jsonp',
                success: function (result) {....}
```

Comment: you should use 2 equal quotation in your if condition to check the value of your dropdown button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Problem:** After I start the debug the `$selcom` always get the value of  `'192.168.5.37'` doesn't matter what I do.

Don't:

```
    if ($("#dropdomain").val('Europa')) {
        $seldom = '192.168.5.37';
    }
    else if ($("#dropdomain").val("Canada")) {
        $seldom = '172.168.0.1';
    }
```

Do:

```
    if ($("#dropdomain").val() === 'Europa') {
        $seldom = '192.168.5.37';
    }
    else if ($("#dropdomain").val() === "Canada") {
        $seldom = '172.168.0.1';
    }
```

See documentation of [`jQuery.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

> ```
> .val(value)
> ```
>
> Description: **Set** the value of each element in the set of matched
>   elements.
>
> `value` argument
>   **Type**: String or Number or Array
>   A string of text, a number, or an array of strings corresponding to the value of each matched element to
>   set as selected/checked.

So, calling `$("#dropdomain").val('some value')` **writes** a value to the `$("#dropdomain")` element. To **read** its value, call `$("#dropdomain").val()`.

Comment: I sure I tried this as well bug probably I had syntax error, not sure. But as I copied your syntax it's working.  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

This condition `$("#dropdomain").val('Europa')` is always writing and is being evaluated as `true`.

**So, you need to compare the values:**

```
var drop = $("#dropdomain").val(); 
if (drop === 'Europa') {
    $seldom = '192.168.5.37';
} else if (drop === "Canada") {
    $seldom = '172.16.0.1';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
var $seldom;
$(document).ready(function () {
    function chkdom() {
        if ($("#dropdomain").val() === 'Europa') {
            $seldom = '192.168.5.37';
        }
        else if ($("#dropdomain").val() === 'Canada') {
            $seldom = '172.16.0.1';
        }
    }
    chkdom();
    alert($seldom);
    alert($("#dropdomain").val());

    $('#search').click(function () {
            chkdom();
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://" + $seldom + "/api/find/" + $("input#user").val(),
                type: "GET",
                dataType: 'Jsonp',
                success: function (result) {....}
```